# Exception in C++ copy constructor

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor, copy

Is it possible to add an exception to copy constructor of a class so that not every variable included in class will be copied? For instance I want every object of my class to have it's own ID.

Comment: What's stopping you, from defining your own copy-constructor? In that case, it will do whatever you want it to do.

Comment: I would rather put the ID in a separate class with that behavior. Easier to maintain

Answer (score 1):

Copy Constructor is called in the following scenarios:

- When we initialize the object with another existing object of the
  same class type. For example, Student s1 = s2, where Student is the
  class.
- When the object of the same class type is passed by value as an
  argument.
- When the function returns the object of the same class type by value.

Yes it possible to add an exception to copy constructor of a class so that not every variable included in class will be copied.Just make parameterized constructor for instances you require,

Code:

```
class A  
{  
   public:  
    int x;  
    A(int a)                // parameterized constructor.  
    {  
      x=a;  
    }  
    A(A &i)               // copy constructor  
    {  
        x = i.x;  
    }  
};  
int main()  
{  
  A a1(20);               // Calling the parameterized constructor.  
 A a2(a1);                //  Calling the copy constructor.  
 cout<<a2.x;  
  return 0;  
}
```